# Adobe Illustrator - Image Tracing and saving as PDF file

Tags: pdf, adobe, vectorization, vector-graphics, adobe-illustrator

I'm making design for juice labels, and my design requires fruits, something like a drawing. So I used image trace on few fruit images and it works well.

In my Illustrator artboard it looks like this:

[image]

But when I save it as PDF file it turns out like this:

[image]

**Question:**
How can I get rid of these lines in PDF file format?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the artefacts of anti-aliasing. Try to turn off these checkboxes in Acrobat Preferences:

[image]

But, actually, this question doesn't belong this department. Post it here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator